# Is this mold in my attic?

Tags: attic, mold

Looks strange but it is only on one panel of wood. Wouldn't mold be spreading across the boards?

There are also a few boards of blue color. That can't be mold can it?
[image: pic 1]

[image: close up]

[image: blue1]

[image: blue2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like weathered OSB roofing in the second picture. The first picture is likely concrete/mortar. Construction companies will generally still use boards that were used for mixing or forming concrete/mortar. If it were mold, it probably wouldn't be isolated to those single boards and would be "creeping" over the roof trusses. So in short, no, it's not mold.

Comment: I tend to agree with tbox.  Is the stuff pictured very hard like hardened concrete or is it soft and easily smeared with your hand?

Comment: Seems to be dusty. Thanks for the feedback everyone!